# How does Random Access File Work

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I 'm starting to learn Java I / O and  i started with Random Access File,I cant find any good information about using Random Access File if some one cant give me some good references to how it works Does it read/write binary or text files? how can i do this? witch are the most correct ways to read/write in files,thanks to all  :)

Comment: Try the Sun/Oracle Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a tutorial like this?

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/randomaccessfile/java-randomaccessfile-example/